# preserving the indecies before shuffling an array

Tags: c#

I use the following to shuffle my byte arrays which is working great and it preserves the indecies of the original order.
because i want to write a deshuffle method, which returns the items to the same order the were in before shuffling, to do this i need to record the indecies before shuffeling so i did the following

```
public static Random rnd=new Random();
public static void Shuffle(this byte[] Bytes,out int[] indecies)
{
    var list = Bytes.Select((b, i) => new Tuple<int, byte>(i, b)).ToArray();
    int n = list.Length;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n--;
        int k = rnd.Next(n + 1);
        Tuple<int, byte> value = list[k];
        list[k] = list[n];
        list[n] = value;
    }

    Bytes = list.Select(tuple => tuple.Item2).ToArray();
    indecies = list.Select(tuple => tuple.Item1).ToArray();
}
```

i am not sure if its the best way but could anyone suggest a way to avoid creating Tuple or creating an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply create another, shuffled array, and keep original array? That even will take less memory, than keeping array of integer indexes.

```
public static byte[] ToShuffledArray(this byte[] bytes)
{
    return bytes.OrderBy(b => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
}
```

Usage:

```
byte[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
byte[] shuffledArray = array.ToShuffledArray();
```

No output parameters, no integer array of indexes.

Comment: not if the arrays will be saved into the database and reordered when loaded, sorry because i didnt say that

Comment: @user1492051 where do you keep array of indexes? In database?

Comment: @user1492051 so, save original array to database and keep shuffled array on local drive

Comment: its the other way round, i started with c# recently still used to the c style of doing things haha, but thats a good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

if anyone wants it the c way then here it is

```
        var indecies =new byte[Bytes.Length];
        for (byte i = 0; i < Bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            indecies[i] = i;
        }
        int n = Bytes.Length;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = ThreadSafeRandom.ThisThreadsRandom.Next(n + 1);
            byte value = Bytes[k];
            byte index = indecies[k];
            Bytes[k] = Bytes[n];
            indecies[k] = indecies[n];
            Bytes[n] = value;
            indecies[n] = index;
        }
```